# MySQL checking if a entry is set

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to check if a entry is set, so for example in a row with: `user, password, birth`
I check if in column user f.e. "mxrlin" is

For that im using that code in my Main Class:

```
if(!mySQL.isSet(tableName, "houseNumber", houseNumberStr)){
            System.out.println(house.getHouseNumber() + " not set yet");
            inserts.add(new BetterMySQL.KeyValue("houseNumber", houseNumberStr));
            mySQL.insertEntry(tableName, inserts);
        }else {
            System.out.println(house.getHouseNumber() + " set -> updating");
            mySQL.update(tableName, inserts, "houseNumber", houseNumberStr);
        }
```

And the mySQL.isSet() method looks like this:

```
public boolean isSet(String tableName, String key, String value){
    Check.checkNotEmpty(tableName);
    Check.checkNotEmpty(key);
    Check.checkNotEmpty(value);
    ResultSet resultSet = MySQL.getResultSetPrepareStatement(connection, "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ?=?", Arrays.asList(key, value));
    try {
        if(resultSet.next()){
            return resultSet.getObject(value) != null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But with this code it always debugs me "house.getHouseNumber() + " not set yet", so the Class doesnt find the entry that is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind a parameter to a column name. The key in this case will be treated as a string literal in SQL.

Assuming a method call like this:

```
mySQL.isSet("houses", "houseNumber", "2335")
```

this code:

```
ResultSet resultSet = MySQL.getResultSetPrepareStatement(connection, "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ?=?", Arrays.asList(key, value));
```

Will generate a SQL statement equivalent to

SELECT * FROM houses WHERE 'houseNumber'='2335'

Of course, the string 'houseNumber' will never equal the string '2335', so no results will be returned.

You'll need to substitute `key` into the SQL string, just like `tableName` already is:

```
ResultSet resultSet = MySQL.getResultSetPrepareStatement(connection, "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + key + "=?", Arrays.asList(value));
```